# The sun can make me - What am I?

Tags: riddle

I am not very specific.

I can be philosopher or gun.

The sun can make me.

So can man.

A trick he learned ages ago.

I was in many hands then.

And I fed and slaughtered the masses.

I am in fewer hands now.

And I see less bloodshed.

But my clash and chime are yet revered.

After Silver and stone.

**What am I?**

Comment: @Ali786 If you have an answer, please post it in the answer section, not the comments. It ruins the fun for people who want to figure it out for themselves.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The answer (after your edit) is:

> bronze

I am not very specific.

> Quoting Wikipedia:
>  Bronze is an alloy consisting primarily of copper, commonly with about
>  12% tin and often with the addition of other metals (such as
>  aluminium, manganese, nickel or zinc) and sometimes non-metals or
>  metalloids such as arsenic, phosphorus or silicon.

I can be philosopher

> The Thinker (French: Le Penseur) is a bronze sculpture by Auguste Rodin.

or gun.

> Gunmetal, also known as red brass in the United States, is a type of bronze – an alloy of copper, tin and zinc.

The sun can make me.

> People are said to be "bronzed by the sun" when they develop a tan.

So can man.

> Fake tan. Alternatively man can forge bronze.

A trick he learned ages ago.

> Bronze was one of the earliest alloys man learnt to make. (OP: Yep.  In the 'Bronze Age')

I was in many hands then.

> Bronze-smithing was a trade known by many

And I fed and slaughtered the masses.

> Bronze weapons were heavily used. (OP: also - Tools for farming and the like were made from bronze)

I am in fewer hands now.

> Not many people can make bronze by themselves and bronze is not as commonly used as it used to be. e.g. bronze coins are less common.

And I see less bloodshed.

> Weapons almost certainly don't use bronze these days.

But my clash and chime are yet revered.

> Bells made of bronze still ring out today. The hammers that strike them are bronze, hence clash. Bronze is also used to make guitar strings, saxophones and banjos, which make be said to 'chime' metaphorically. (OP: also - Cymbals are often bronze and make a clashing sound)

After Silver

> Bronze is less precious than silver (OP: also - Silver: Second-Place, Bronze: Third-Place)

and stone.

> The bronze age came after the stone age.

Comment: Well Done.  This is the correct answer.  +1

Comment: @BrentHackers In fairness to the other answerers, I probably would have said the same as either of them had their answers not been ruled out and the last clue not given.

Comment: That is entirely fair with regards to the answer given by @Ankoganit at least.  I do think that the answer above is a better fit (although not all of the explanations above are complete).  I will add an OP explanation as soon as I can.  That said, I hope do hope everyone upvotes Ankoganit's answer!

Answer (score 17):

EDIT: This answer was given before the OP edited his puzzle with an additional last line.

I think you're

> stone.

I am not very specific.

> Stone can refer to various things: minerals, gems, or just solid rocks.

I can be philosopher or gun.

> [Philosopher's stone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Philosopher's_stone), [gunstone](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/gunstone).

The sun can make me.
So can man.

> [Sunstone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sunstone), [stoneman](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stoneman).

A trick he learned ages ago.
I was in many hands then.
And I fed and slaughtered the masses.

> Men learnt the use of stones in the stone age. Most people used stones at that time. It was used to hunt down animals (to "feed" the masses) and even to kill other humans ("slaughtered the masses").

I am in fewer hands now.
And I see less bloodshed.
But my clash and chime are yet revered.

> Few people use (directly) stones nowadays. It's rarely ever used to kill people. But we still remember the connections of stone with history and the ancient wars.

Comment: Excellent answer!  Such a good fit (almost as good as my answer), and with good reason.  I guess I left this a little broad (sorry).  I think I'll need to update the puzzle with one more line to improve it.  You should totally be able to get it now though.  You're just a little too 'early' +1.

Comment: @BrentHackers Hmmm, it's OK. This is a nice puzzle. :-)

Answer (score 13):

Is it

> fire?

I am not very specific.

> Fire can occur in many forms

I can be philosopher or gun.

> The Greek philosopher Heraclitus [thought fire was the basic material of the world](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/heraclitus/); **gun**fire

The sun can make me.

> the heat of the sun can create fire

So can man.

> humans can create fires too

A trick he learned ages ago.

> we learned that quite a while ago

I was in many hands then.

> many people can make a fire?

And I fed and slaughtered the masses.

> many people got killed in fire accidents

I am in fewer hands now.

And I see less bloodshed.

But my clash and chime are yet revered.

> people feel respect for fire

Comment: Some really good fits and sort of thinking along the right lines +1.  Not what I'm looking for though.

Comment: This was my first thought too.

Comment: The last two are the only that seem dubious. In the first of the last two you might wish to mention cooking and weaponisation, and in the last you may want to mention how many people do not create it by hand any more, they have devices to craete it for them. (Sorry if that's cryptic, I'm trying to not spoil it for the people who don't like reading the spoilers.)

Comment: @Pharap yes, that was my problem too. I had a hard time trying to come up with suitable reasoning for the last few lines.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe

> "Energy"?
>  -Can be created by sun or man,
>  -fed and also slaughtered (like atomic bombs) masses ,
>  -can occur in many many forms
>  etc.

Comment: Welcome to puzzling @Dui. This probably isn't a bad answer when I think about it but, you should provide a full explanation for your answer against each clue (where you can), and if you want to add a spoiler (which I strongly recommend) use >! at the start of a line.  Although I would point out the [First Law Of Thermodynamics](https://www.boundless.com/chemistry/textbooks/boundless-chemistry-textbook/thermodynamics-17/the-laws-of-thermodynamics-123/the-three-laws-of-thermodynamics-496-3601/).